# Display a JavaScript variable value but not in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form to work out an order value for checkout.

I want to display the total (totalAmt) and order code (combinedentries) on the form.

I want a nice total at the bottom rather than a plain old text box.

I want the contents of the two text boxes at the bottom of the order form formatted as text rather than entries in input boxes.

I want to format the total to the same green background colour as title banners with the writing in black.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function calcTotal(form)
{
    var totalElem = null;
    var prodAmt = 0;
    var packAmt = 0;
    var printAmt = 0;
    var designAmt = 0;
    var totalAmt = 0;
    var combinedentries = null;
    var descrip = null;
    var desc = null;
    var itemname = null;
    var rewardscalc = 0;
    var rewards = 0;


    try
    {
        prodAmt=parseFloat(form["prodamount"].value,2);
        packAmt=parseFloat(form["packamount"].value,2);

        printAmt=parseFloat(form["printOpt"].value,2);
        designAmt=parseFloat(form["graphicOpt"].value,2);

        totalAmt = parseFloat(prodAmt+packAmt+printAmt+designAmt,2);
        rewardscalc = (totalAmt/5);
        rewards = rewardscalc >> 0;
        totalElem=document.getElementById("amount");
        totalElem.value = totalAmt.toString();

    combinedentries = prodAmt.toString() + ":" +  packAmt.toString() + ":" + printAmt.toString() +":" + designAmt.toString() +"/" +rewards;

    descrip=document.getElementById("description");
        descrip.value = "A7F/" + combinedentries

    desc=document.getElementById("desc");
        desc.value = "A7F/" + combinedentries

    itemname=document.getElementById("item_name");
        itemname.value = "A7F/" + combinedentries

    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = item_name;

    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("calcTotal Error:  " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }

}
</script> 

</head>
<body>
<form id="orderform" name = "orderform" onchange="calcTotal(this)">


<font color="#f4f2e6">

<h1 style="color: #f4f2e6; background-color: #2ec447; font-size: 1.5em; margin-left: 0em;padding: 0.4em; width 500px;">  " A7 Leaflets (A7L)"</h1>
<br/>

<h1 style="color: #f4f2e6; background-color: #2ec447; font-size: 1.25em; margin 0.4em; width 500px; padding 0.4em;">   Order Quantity Required</h1>

<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="36.00" checked> 5,000<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="45.00"> 10,000<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="68.00"> 15,000<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="73.00"> 20,000<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="89.00"> 25,000<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="112.00"> 30,000<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="117.00"> 35,000<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="133.00"> 40,000<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="150.00"> 45,000<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="165.00"> 50,000<br/>

<h1 style="color: #f4f2e6; background-color: #2ec447; font-size: 1.25em; margin 50px; width 500px; padding 0.4em;">   Product Material & Finish</h1>

<input type="radio" name="packamount" value="1.00" checked> 130gm Art Paper Silk Finish <br/>
<input type="radio" name="packamount" value="2.00"> 130gm Art Paper Gloss Finish <br/>
<input type="radio" name="packamount" value="15.00"> 170gm Art Paper Silk Finish <br/>
<input type="radio" name="packamount" value="16.00"> 170gm Art Paper Gloss Finish<br/>

<h1 style="color: #f4f2e6; background-color: #2ec447; font-size: 1.25em; margin 50px; width 500px; padding 0.4em;">   Number Of Sides Printed</h1>

<!-- 3rd option printopt -->
<input type="radio" name="printOpt" value="0.00" checked > Single Sided Print (Included)<br/>
<input type="radio" name="printOpt" value="5.00" > Double Sided Print <br/>

<h1 style="color: #f4f2e6; background-color: #2ec447; font-size: 1.25em; margin 50px; width 500px; padding 0.4em;">   Artwork Options</h1>

<!-- 4th option graphic opt -->
<input type="radio" name="graphicOpt" value="0.00" checked > Supply Own Checked Artwork (Included)<br/>
<input type="radio" name="graphicOpt" value="5.00" > Artwork Checking Service <br/>
<input type="radio" name="graphicOpt" value="10.00" > Single Side Artwork Design Service <br/>
<input type="radio" name="graphicOpt" value="15.00" > Double Side Artwork Design Service <br/>

<font color="#2ec447">
<br/>
<br/>
<!-- box here displaying the total preferable without having to click a recalculate button -->
<br/>

<input type="type" id="amount" name="amount" value="0"/>
<div id="totalAmt"></div>

<input type="hidden" id="description" name="description" value="0"/>
<div id="totalAmt"></div>

<input type="hidden"  id="desc" name="desc" value="0"/>
<div id="totalAmt"></div>

<input type="item_name" onFocus="blur()" id="item_name" name="item_name" label = "£ "value="0"/>
<div id="totalAmt"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="info@creaitve.co.uk"> <!-- nochex required -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@creaitve.co.uk">  <!-- paypal required -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"> <!-- paypal required -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> <!-- paypal required -->
<input name="instId" type="hidden" value="1243833" /> <!-- worldpay required -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP"> <!-- worldpay required -->
<input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="CreaITve"> <!-- worldpay cart name -->
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="CreaITve"> <!-- nochex cart name -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="CreaITve"> <!-- paypal cart name  -->
<input type="hidden" name="desc" value="Print Service A7 Flyers" & printOpt> <!-- worldpay product name -->
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="Print Service A7 Flyers" & printOpt> <!-- nochex product name -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Print Service A7 Flyers" & printOpt> <!-- paypal product name  -->
<div style="text-align:center"> 

<h1>"the value for number is: " <span id="myText"></span></h1>

<input type='submit' name='worldpay' value='WorldPay' formAction="https://secure.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" method="POST"><autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return verifyfields()">
<input type='submit' name='nochex' value='NoChex' formAction="https://secure.nochex.com/"><autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return verifyfields()">
<input type='submit' name='paypal' value='Paypal' formAction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
</div> 

</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // Calculate the initial total
    calcTotal(document.getElementById("orderform"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whitespace and fewer words help people understand what your question is faster and therefore help you better.

Comment: so whats the problem ? Question is unclear to me.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp That's how to add new HTML to the page which is what you appear to want to do.